# ¿Cómo agrego una medida en pixeles a scrollTop?

Tags: jquery, html5, menú

Tengo el siguiente código para realizar un menú pegajoso con JQuery, pero quisiera que la medida que me admita antes de que genere el menú sea en pixeles.

========================================================================

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if( $(this).scrollTop() > 1){
        $('header').addClass('scroll');
    } else {
        $('header').removeClass('scroll');
    }
});
});
```

Comment: La medida que da javascript es en pixeles

Comment: Antes que nada muchas gracias por la replica, en este caso estoy declarando que cuando **scrolllTop()** con 'if( $(this).scrollTop() > 1)' sea activado agregue una clase de nombre scroll al header, pero si paso ese **1** a pixeles no me agrega la clase, podrías ser mas especifico porfavor

Comment: Es que cuando haces $(this).scrollTop() > 1, ya ese uno esta especificado en pixeles, y el scrolltop tambien esta especificado en pixeles, osea jquery y javascript trabaja con pixeles

Comment: Tienes razón, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, abusando de tu amabilidad, ¿podrías ayudarme con otra consulta?

Comment: La función `scrollTop()` devuelve el número de píxeles que quedan ocultos en la parte superior del área que tiene el *scroll*. No devuelve la unidad de píxeles pero el número equivale a píxeles.

Comment: Haahaha, dale, no no abusas de mi amabilidad, dime cual es tu otra consulta, tambien gracias blonfu por la aclaracion

Comment: jejeje Gracias, veras, ya tengo que mi menú pegajoso se active a los 250px, pero que una parte del **header** se oculte, esto hace que mi **seccion principal** se recorra de manera drástica y que todos mis elementos se oculten debajo de mi menú sin que sean apreciados de manera correcta

Comment: A ver, no te entiendo, podrias mostrarme o darme un ejemplo, enseñar un screenshot o algo?

Comment: ¿podría contactarte por hangouts?, para poder mostrarte mi pantalla mejor

Answer (score -1):

Esta línea de código me funcionó a mí:

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '75px'}, 800);
```

Comment: ¿En qué medida te ayudó? ¿Podrías dar más detalles al respecto? Lee [answer] para más info :)